# swap x and y axis of a 2d vector

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

Consider a 2d vector like this:

```
(def v2d [["a" "b" "c"]
          ["d" "e" "f"]
          ["g" "h" "i"]])
```

I need to **swap the x and the v axis.** So it needs to be turned into:

```
[["a" "d" "g"]
 ["b" "e" "h"]
 ["c" "f" "i"]]
```

I came up with this solution:

```
(defn swap-xy [v2d]
  (apply mapv (fn [& args] (vec args)) v2d))
```

I'm just asking myself if there is one unnecessary step inside. The type of the variable args turns out to be: `clojure.lang.PersistentVector$ChunkedSeq` . That's why I have to turn it to a vector again by the use of the function `vec`.
Could the conversion be avoided?

here's a small benchmark regarding the questioned conversion:

```
user=> (time (def x (apply (fn [& args] args) (range 10000000))))
"Elapsed time: 0.446455 msecs"
#'user/x
user=> (time (def x (apply (fn [& args] (vec args)) (range 10000000))))
"Elapsed time: 721.011768 msecs"
#'user/x
```

Comment: Depending on your application, you may find [`core.matrix`](https://github.com/mikera/core.matrix) useful.  It includes a `transpose` function that would do the same thing as your function.

Comment: wow, that looks very promising, I'll might need this, hence my next problem to solve would have been how to write words in rows or in columns to the 2d-vec..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function redefines `vector`, it would be more idiomatic to write it as `(apply mapv vector v2d)`.

BTW, do you really need it to be a vector? It's significantly faster to generate a sequence of vectors: `(apply map vector v2d)`.

Also, benchmarking with `time` is not very accurate. It's best to use a tool such as [Criterium](https://github.com/hugoduncan/criterium).

Comment: Is it faster to generate a *realised* sequence of vectors?